# why does my list keep changing after using for loop to append?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, random, append

I've created a function that produces n number of random k-combinations of tuples from the list below (example is 5 sets of 6 tuples). Though the function works as expected, every time I run the script it overwrites what was previously appended to rand_list.

```
list_a=[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 5), (0, 10), (0, 20), (0, 50), (0, 100), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 5), (2, 10), (2, 20), (2, 50), (2, 100), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 5), (5, 10), (5, 20), (5, 50), (5, 100), (10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 5), (10, 10), (10, 20), (10, 50), (10, 100), (20, 1), (20, 2), (20, 5), (20, 10), (20, 20), (20, 50), (20, 100), (50, 1), (50, 2), (50, 5), (50, 10), (50, 20), (50, 50), (50, 100), (100, 1), (100, 2), (100, 5), (100, 10), (100, 20), (100, 50), (100, 100)]
```

```
import random
rand_list=[]

def rand_gen(n):

i=[random.choices(list_a, k=6) for r in range(n)]
    for x in i:
        if x not in rand_list:
            rand_list.append(x)

rand_gen(5)
print(rand_list)
```

e.g. first run output:

```
print(rand_list) >>> [[(0, 50), (50, 10), (10, 20), (10, 1), (20, 20), (5, 2)], [(0, 5), (50, 5), (0, 50), (5, 20), (5, 100), (0, 10)], [(100, 2), (50, 10), (10, 2), (50, 100), (0, 1), (20, 10)], [(20, 2), (50, 2), (20, 100), (50, 2), (20, 10), (5, 5)], [(100, 5), (0, 20), (100, 10), (50, 100), (5, 1), (10, 50)]]
```

second run output

```
print(rand_list) >>> [[(2, 1), (5, 5), (10, 1), (5, 100), (0, 5), (0, 100)], [(5, 10), (100, 1), (100, 100), (2, 10), (0, 5), (5, 50)], [(50, 2), (5, 100), (0, 5), (100, 5), (10, 50), (20, 1)], [(20, 50), (10, 10), (2, 5), (5, 50), (100, 1), (0, 50)], [(10, 1), (0, 10), (10, 20), (10, 2), (5, 2), (10, 20)]]
```

How do I get it to stay the same? I want to use rand_list elsewhere but I can't if it just changes every time i run the script and so is not stable. IDE is sublime text if that's relevant.

how do i get the list to be stable i.e. only producing what was in the first run regardless of how many times the script is run?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, if you want to build the list using a random process you can't expect to have a deterministic output. If you want to have a fixed outcome you shoud not rely on random.

Comment: I just want to store what was randomly generated in a list, for use elsewhere. There's surely a way to do that?

Comment: What's `random` means to you?

Comment: doesn't answer my question. what does the use of random have to do with the stored values getting wiped and replaced with new ones every time its run?

Comment: The code you have shownus here does nothing else than setting your variable to a new random value, so it is really hard to understand what you are trying to acomplish. If you want to use your variable after you set it to this random value then you can do so, if you want to store it in a file also...

Comment: I don't see what's so unclear. If you copy in the function and run it a few times you will see that the generated values change every time you run it. I want to keep what is generated the first time around so i can use the values elsewhere. Would you have any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: If you want to keep the same value just refactor your code to not use a random process, as the hole point of using randomness is to have a random outcome...

Comment: that's my problem though, the list and number of combinations are too large to make a close ended list (using product function) to iterate through one by one. in my example there are 49 elements in the list and 6 combinations (with replacement ), meaning a list of 13bn. If i want to expand the list or increase the combinations this gets even worse, hence why am wanting to use random function, to take a sample from the range of possible combinations. If there is no way of using random function then I guess I have no way of solving my problem then.